# How configuration is effected into code flow?

Tags: configuration, config

Different kind of software offer different amount of configuration/customization. Routers are one of the most configurable software systems I know of. I want to know how routers handle configurations - how they alter the code flow based on the configuration?

One obvious way is to use if..else clauses provided by most of the language(let's assume we are using C)
So is there any other programming method(or paradigm?)

Data-driven programming paradigm may be viable one. Configuration can be thought of one of the input source and so can be used to alter the code flow.
What I need to know is, is there any papers and references that I can use to enrich my understanding. Not just routers any kind of software. If the question seems to vague, let me know I will add more details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about configuration of routers, but your question states you are interested in configuration for any kind of software, so the following might be of interest to you.

I am the author of [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/), which provides C++ and Java parsers for a particular configuration syntax. I suggest you do the following. Skim Chapters 2 and 3 of the "Config4* Getting Started Guide" ([HTML](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide), [PDF](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-getting-started-guide.pdf)) to get an overview of the configuration syntax and API. Then take your time reading the "Config4* Practical Usage Guide" ([HTML](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-practical-usage-guide), [PDF](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-practical-usage-guide.pdf)), which discusses the "how to" for a variety of different ways to use configuration. Although the discussion in that manual makes use of the Config4* syntax and API, the principles could be used with another syntax, for example, XML. If you focus on the principles discussed in that manual, rather than the syntax, then I suspect you will start to develop some insight into how a router handles its configuration.

Comment: This sounds interesting but what I need is how the code-flow is determined after all the configuration is done. If I have 10 parameters deciding execution of one block, should it appear like this -- if (param1 = = val1 && param2 == val2 ... && param10 == val10) { }

Comment: One way would be to use a complex if-then-else statement. Another way would be to use configuration variables to create objects chosen from a class hierarchy. Then the code flow might simply be to call virtual operations on the objects. Yet another way would be to use configuration settings to populate, say, a hash table. The code flow might be simply to perform lookups on the hash table.